# Error http 500 at wordpress installation on a local LEMP installation

Tags: linux, nginx, wordpress, 500-error

I’m new on Nginx, and don’t have much experience of WordPress. On Fedora 31 workstation, I installed locally LEMP according to [linuxtechi.com](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-lemp-stack-fedora-30-server) . Then I installed wordpress through the dnf install command, and used [Kifarunix.com](https://kifarunix.com/install-wordpress-5-with-nginx-on-fedora-30-fedora-29) , but I adapted it a bit because I want to install several websites. http://localhost/info.php works, so Nginx and PHP work. But WordPress doesn’t. I first got a WordPress screen asking me to be ready to give the database password etc, then another one saying that wp-config.php (if I remember well) couldn’t be created: I didn’t mind, because I had already written the database password etc. in it, so I tried to go on, not to avail. Now, on http://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php , I get “The file wp-config.php already exists. If you need to reset any of the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may try installing now.” and if I click on the link, I get error 500. The file install.php where I’m redirected to (exactly, a hard link to the file) is in /usr/share/wordpress/example.com/wp-admin/ and belongs to user nginx, with read write permission for the owner. /etc/nginx/nginx.conf includes a line
`include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`; and /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf includes the lines

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    root         /usr/share/wordpress/example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.example.com;

    index   index.php;

    location / {
        try_files    $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

etc..

Comment: Might it be you have `default_server` in two separate `server{}` blocks with `listen 80`? In that case, remove it from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf`. Only one server per ip:port can be the default.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did have "default_server" twice and removed it from /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf , so now the line just says `listen 80;`. Is this OK?
Then I restarted nginx but the problem is still there.

Comment: I think I currently can't help you any further, but we have ruled out one problem anyway, making it a bit more likely you'd get an actual answer. This is a good question with a lot of relevant details. Actually very good for a first question here!